# Line break with equations in game tree labels produced with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, line-breaking, trees

I use this manual for help with the drawing of game trees using TikZ (http://www.sfu.ca/~haiyunc/notes/Game_Trees_with_TikZ.pdf).

However, I have a challenge I cannot seem to overcome. Some of my end-nodes require line breaks in the labels. In the concrete example below, in the end node on the left in the second branch (after "Not Resist"), I would like the equation after the two vertical lines (||) to be placed below the first equation. In other words split the line between the X and the U_S.

I have tried by specifying "`align=centre`" and using `\\` but it did not work. Similarly, I tried specifying an equation environment within the label, but it did not work either.

Any help would be most appreciated.

An MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    solid node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black},
    hollow node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,font=\footnotesize]
    \tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=15mm, sibling distance=20mm]
    \tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=15mm, sibling distance=20mm]
          \node(0)[solid node,label=above:{\textbf{Sender}}]{}
              child{node(1)[hollow node, label=below:{$U_S(SQ)$}]{}
              edge from parent node[left,xshift=-3,yshift=5]{\textit{Not Threaten}}
              }
              child{node(2)[solid node, label=above right:{\textbf{Target}}]{}
                  child{node[hollow node, label=below:{$U_S(TS)=X$ \\ $||U_T(TS)=Y$}]{} edge from parent node[left,xshift=-3,yshift=0]{\textit{Not Resist}}}
                  child{node[hollow node, label=below:{$TF$}]{} edge from parent node[right,xshift=3,yshift=0]{\textit{Resist}}}
                  edge from parent node[right,xshift=3,yshift=5]{\textit{Threaten}}
                  };
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: A game tree model]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `\makecell`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    solid node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black},
    hollow node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,font=\footnotesize]
    \tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=15mm, sibling distance=20mm]
    \tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=15mm, sibling distance=20mm]
          \node(0)[solid node,label=above:{\textbf{Sender}}]{}
              child{node(1)[hollow node, label=below:{$U_S(SQ)$}]{}
              edge from parent node[left,xshift=-3,yshift=5]{\textit{Not Threaten}}
              }
              child{node(2)[solid node, label=above right:{\textbf{Target}}]{}
                  child{node[hollow node, label=below:{\makecell{$U_S(TS)=X$ \\ $||U_T(TS)=Y$}}]{} edge from parent node[left,xshift=-3,yshift=0]{\textit{Not Resist}}}
                  child{node[hollow node, label=below:{$TF$}]{} edge from parent node[right,xshift=3,yshift=0]{\textit{Resist}}}
                  edge from parent node[right,xshift=3,yshift=5]{\textit{Threaten}}
                  };
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. A simple and straightforward solution. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Stack it!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    solid node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black},
    hollow node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,font=\footnotesize]
    \tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=15mm, sibling distance=20mm]
    \tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=15mm, sibling distance=20mm]
          \node(0)[solid node,label=above:{\textbf{Sender}}]{}
              child{node(1)[hollow node, label=below:{$U_S(SQ)$}]{}
              edge from parent node[left,xshift=-3,yshift=5]{\textit{Not Threaten}}
              }
              child{node(2)[solid node, label=above right:{\textbf{Target}}]{}
                  child{node[hollow node, label=below:{\stackunder{$U_S(TS)=X ||$}{%
                     $U_T(TS)=Y$}}]{} edge from parent node[left,xshift=-3,yshift=0]{\textit{Not Resist}}}
                  child{node[hollow node, label=below:{$TF$}]{} edge from parent node[right,xshift=3,yshift=0]{\textit{Resist}}}
                  edge from parent node[right,xshift=3,yshift=5]{\textit{Threaten}}
                  };
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want it aligned, tabstack it (note: for some reason, the `||` needed additional grouping inside the `\slignstackunder`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    solid node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black},
    hollow node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,font=\footnotesize]
    \tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=15mm, sibling distance=20mm]
    \tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=15mm, sibling distance=20mm]
          \node(0)[solid node,label=above:{\textbf{Sender}}]{}
              child{node(1)[hollow node, label=below:{$U_S(SQ)$}]{}
              edge from parent node[left,xshift=-3,yshift=5]{\textit{Not Threaten}}
              }
              child{node(2)[solid node, label=above right:{\textbf{Target}}]{}
                  child{node[hollow node, label=below:{\alignstackunder{U_S(TS)=&X {||}}{%
                     U_T(TS)=&Y}}]{} edge from parent node[left,xshift=-3,yshift=0]{\textit{Not Resist}}}
                  child{node[hollow node, label=below:{$TF$}]{} edge from parent node[right,xshift=3,yshift=0]{\textit{Resist}}}
                  edge from parent node[right,xshift=3,yshift=5]{\textit{Threaten}}
                  };
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit: `istgame` v2.0 (codes improved for tree parts)

With the [`istgame`](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) v2.0, you can easily control the input modes and fonts for important labels using a new macro `\setistmathTF*`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{istgame}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}[scale=1.5,font=\footnotesize]
\setistmathTF*001<textbf>
\xtShowEndPoints[oval node]
\setistSolidNodeStyle{4pt}
\xtdistance{15mm}{20mm}
\istroot(0){Sender}
  \istb{Not Threaten}[al]{U_S(SQ)}
  \istb*{Threaten}[ar]
  \endist
\istroot(1)(0-2)<45>{Target}
  \istb{Not\ Resist}[al]{\mbox{\makecell{$U_S(TS)=X$\\$\|U_T(TS)=Y$}}}
  \istb{Resist}[ar]{TF}
  \endist
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```

#### Original answer (istgame v1.0)

This is an example that uses the [`istgame`](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) package to draw the game tree and the `makecell` pacakage for the line break.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{istgame}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}[scale=1.5,font=\footnotesize]
\xtShowEndPoints[oval node]
\setistSolidNodeStyle{4pt}
\xtdistance{15mm}{20mm}
\istroot(0)
  \istb{Not\ Threaten}[al]{U_S(SQ)}
  \istb*{Threaten}[ar]
  \endist
\istroot(1)(0-2)
  \istb{Not\ Resist}[al]{\mbox{\makecell{$U_S(TS)=X$\\$\|U_T(TS)=Y$}}}
  \istb{Resist}[ar]{TF}
  \endist
\xtOwner(0){\textbf{Sender}}
\xtOwner(1){\textbf{Target}}[ar]
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

you only need add to label style `align=center`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    solid node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black},
    hollow node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5},
    every label/.append style={align=center}% <--- added
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,font=\footnotesize]
    \tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=15mm, sibling distance=20mm]
    \tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=15mm, sibling distance=20mm]
          \node(0)[solid node,label=above:{\textbf{Sender}}]{}
              child{node(1)[hollow node, label=below:{$U_S(SQ)$}]{}
              edge from parent node[left,xshift=-3,yshift=5]{\textit{Not Threaten}}
              }
              child{node(2)[solid node, label=above right:{\textbf{Target}}]{}
                  child{node[hollow node, label=below:{$U_S(TS)=X$ \\ $||U_T(TS)=Y$}]{} edge from parent node[left,xshift=-3,yshift=0]{\textit{Not Resist}}}
                  child{node[hollow node, label=below:{$TF$}]{} edge from parent node[right,xshift=3,yshift=0]{\textit{Resist}}}
                  edge from parent node[right,xshift=3,yshift=5]{\textit{Threaten}}
                  };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `amsmath` and `gathered`; the reason for `\!` is explained elsewhere in the site.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  solid node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black},
  hollow node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,font=\footnotesize]
\tikzset{
  level 1/.style={level distance=15mm, sibling distance=20mm},
  level 2/.style={level distance=15mm, sibling distance=20mm},
}
\node(0)[solid node,label=above:{\textbf{Sender}}]{}
  child{
    node(1)[hollow node, label=below:{$U_S(SQ)$}]{}
    edge from parent node[left,xshift=-3,yshift=5]{\textit{Not Threaten}}
  }
  child{
    node(2)[solid node, label=above right:{\textbf{Target}}]{}
    child{
      node[hollow node, label=below:{
        $\!\begin{gathered}U_S(TS)=X \\ ||U_T(TS)=Y\end{gathered}$}]{} 
      edge from parent node[left,xshift=-3,yshift=0]{\textit{Not Resist}}}
      child{
        node[hollow node, label=below:{$TF$}]{} 
        edge from parent node[right,xshift=3,yshift=0]{\textit{Resist}}}
        edge from parent node[right,xshift=3,yshift=5]{\textit{Threaten}}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.

[image]